# help with table

Tags: tables, status

I have been asked to review a table layout.

The table contains a list of reports which the user can sort and perform various actions on:
[image]

I have been asked to work within the confines of the CMS and actions must be on the left hand side.
the actions are: run report, edit report properties, set report scheduling, set report privacy, other actions (...)
the problem is there is a business requirement for the user to be able to see at a glance the state of sharing (shared, private) and the state of scheduling (scheduled, not scheduled) and this is done by the different icons in the latter two action columns. The user can click on either of these 'stated' icons to change the state of sharing or scheduling.

my question:
It is not obvious the user can click on the inactive states to edit. How can I indicate state differences whilst also ensuring these two states are editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need slightly enhanced toggle buttons.

i.e. a common button frame which indicates 'clickable', which when clicked (and any properties panel dismissed) then changes the symbol within the frame to indicate state - like a checkbox has a frame and a tick/cross/empty state.

How you design that is up to you - but here's a quick mock up:

[image]

Note the time on a 'schedule' button changes and looks like a tick.

If unscheduled the clock part of the icon is grey but the main schedule icon remains coloured.

The sharing button might just change the padlock/shared icon or could bring up a popup to change attributes - depends on how you set up the sharing in your scenario.

Comment: hello roger! long time no see! aye, the calendar state is ace. And ive gone back to business to moan about how the states of sharing are not shared or private but shared or not shared.